# Applying events only to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have a `div` which is quite large.

Inside the `div` I have several other `elements`.

When clicking and dragging the `parent div`, if it has overflow, I want it to drag it (found a library to do it).

If clicking and dragging the `elements`, I want to drag the `element` (also found a library for it).

Right now, the problem is when I click and drag the `parent div`, it works fine, but when I click and drag the `element`, it drags the `element` and drags the `parent`.

All libraries work by the terms of providing a `jQuery selector`.

Is it possible to specify something like `$('#parent_div and :notInsideElements')`, or something like that?

**EDIT:**

The two libraries I am using are [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/) and [UtterScroll](http://www.debiki.com/dev/utterscroll)

As for markup - I create a paper for JointJS and then to the paper container apply the UtterScroll.

Comment: Please include the markup you have in the question.

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: What library are you using? - jqueryUI?

Comment: If you're selecting an id then the style you apply will only effect that element.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ this may be what you're looking for. On drag of child, stop propogation. Not sure if you have access to that, so I won't post as answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your onDrag handler use `event.stopPropagation();` this will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
});

paper.on('cell:pointermove', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

I'm not sure if you can combine events, as nothing in the docs says so. However, it's worth trying

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown cell:pointermove', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Nope, did not help. The dragging of the paper gets called first.